# matching tool in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to have access return address that matches in a table. Currently i am getting below results since i have Expressions matching for only left 3:
Expr1: ((Left([Sales].[ShipToAddress1],3)=Left([HPG ROSTER].[Address1],3)))

ShipToAddress1            Address1

10420  VISTA DEL SOL    10420 Vista Del Sol

10420  VISTA DEL SOL    10460 Vista Del Sol

10301 GATEWAY WEST            10301 Gateway West

3535 S. I35E              3535 S. I-35 East

3535 S. I35E               3537 South I-35

Is there a way to have access match only "numbers" from Shipto address and numbers from Address 1 instead of left 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use Instr and search for the first space.

I think this should work for you:

```
((Instr(1, [Sales].[ShipToAddress1], ' ') = Instr(1, [HPG ROSTER].[Address1], ' '))
```

NOTE: You'll also want to match on something like the zipcode.

Comment: I tried using your statement tmatching state and city and after that it is still giving me wrong matches.                   ShipToAddress1           Address 1
483 WEST SEED FARM ROAD 483 W Seed Farm Rd
483 WEST SEED FARM ROAD    477 W Seed Farm Rd
100 EAST LE FEVRE ROAD    100 E Le Fevre Rd
100 EAST LE FEVRE ROAD    101 E Miller Rd
12251 SOUTH 80TH AVENUE   12251 S 80th Ave
401 MATTHEW STREET          802 Wayne St
401 MATTHEW STREET          611 2nd St
100 MARIO CAPECCHI DR 100 Mario Capecchi Dr
100 MARIO CAPECCHI DR Ave 8th C St

Comment: Make sure you are using AND's for your additional state and city matching logic and not OR's. That could be the issue.